# с++: безопасное удаление указателей с последующим их обнулением

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, c++14, c++17

Подскажите в новых стандартах C++ не появились ли удаления указателей в 1 строчку, чтобы не писать код:

```
if (ptr != nullptr)
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}
```

или (если выделялся массив)

```
if (ptr != nullptr)
{
    delete [] ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}
```

может есть что-нибудь типа `stl::one_line_delete(ptr)` ?

Comment: умные указатели (они давно есть)

Comment: мне казалось, что умный в данном случае избыточен, т.е. я про ситуацию, где надо в конкретной ситуации удалить данные и быть уверенным, что указатель будет нулевым, если к нему обратиться

Comment: но эти ситуации возникают редко, и не думаю, что в стандарт введут  что нибудь подобное.  Вы вполне можете написать сами(функцию, макрос), и эту двустрочную функцию никак не напишут в стандарте лучше. И почему же умные указатели избыточны? Они ведь ничем не ухудшают код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, если хотите

```
template<typename T>
void destroy(T*& p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}
```

Не вижу особой необходимости, не всегда же удаляется по переменной, но...

Кстати, проверка `if (ptr != nullptr)` избыточна.